# Need Help using webbrowser in python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-webbrowser

I made an app that opens urls in a web browser, when you enter them into a gui.

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def WebOpen():
    url = (WebEntry.get())
    webbrowser.open(url)

gui = Tk()

gui.after(1, lambda: gui.focus_force)

gui.geometry("1920x1040")

gui.resizable(False, False)

gui.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

gui.configure(bg="black")

ExitWindow = Label(gui, text="To Quit This Computer Application, On Your Keyboard, Press and Hold the ALT and the F4 keys at the bottom and top of your keyboard respectively.", fg="white", bg="black", font="arial, 21")
ExitWindow.place(x=30,y=5)

WebEntry = Entry(gui, font="arial, 21")
WebEntry.place(x=100,y=400)

WebButton = Button(gui, text="Take Me There!",font="arial, 21",command=WebOpen())
WebButton.place(x=200, y=500)

gui.mainloop()
```

I tried to use webbrowser and tkinter to make an app that opens a webpage, but as soon as my program started, it opened file explorer (I think because of an empty path or something.)

Comment: I believe the reason is because you used `command=WebOpen()`.  The purpose of the `command` argument is to give the name of a function to be called _later_.  But because you included the parentheses `()` after the function, it is called _immediately_ when the button is created.  I think you should use `command=WebOpen` instead, without the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis in the line 26. It works alright after removal

```
WebButton = Button(gui, text="Take Me There!",font="arial, 21",command=WebOpen)
```

Comment: When writing an answer, please try to explain the solution or close the question as a duplicate. That way OP is less likely to make the same mistake again.

Comment: If anyone had the same issue, and want to know why, please check John Gordon's comment on the original answer! Thank you both!